# How to deal with checked exception that is impossible to be thrown

Tags: java

I want to new a url object, and do something with the url.

For example,

```
void downloadPage()
{
    URL url=new URL("http://www.google.com");
    do(url);
}
```

The code doesn't compile because the URL constructor declares `MalformatedException`, I have to either declare the exception or try-catch it. But I think none of two ways make sense, because the url string doesn't change, this exception is impossible to be thrown.

How should I deal with this situation?

Comment: Catch it and have the catch throw InternalError.

Comment: @HotLicks I know for a fact that's the way the JDK does clone but I thought InternalError indicated a JVM problem.

Comment: @Radiodef - And it would, for the above code.  One could pick a different error, but it should be an Error, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
try {
    throwsCheckedException();
} catch(CheckedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

This way the exception is still thrown if you are wrong but you don't have to deal with it if you are really sure it won't happen. This is probably not appropriate for production code. If the program is important to someone that's not you, a better solution may be to log it in the appropriate manner.

You really can't be sure an exception will never throw, I've personally had it happen a couple of times where I was pretty sure it wouldn't and it did.

The other way is to handle it in a sissy way:

```
// in some utility class
public static void exitWithError(Throwable e, String msg) {
    dumpStackTraceToFile(e); // something you should have
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    System.exit(1); // force JVM exit when the dialog closes
}

// wherever this should be, only do it once
static final URL GOOGLE;
static {
    try {
        GOOGLE = new URL("http://google.com");
    } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        exitWithError(e, "Somebody changed the Google URL!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really a smart solution! It preserves the exception and let me ignore it in the upper level.

Comment: You just have to be sure that if it does throw, nothing dangerous will happen. See my edit for the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could just surround it in a try/catch like so from my understanding.

```
void downloadPage()
{

try {

  URL url=new URL("http://www.google.com");
   do(url);

} catch(MalformedException me) { 
     System.out.println("caught this: " + me);
}


}
```

Comment: That approach is pretty dangerous, for a "should never occur" situation.  You catch the error and basically ignore it, plus the operation is not completed.  The app will fail and no one will know why.

Comment: Well, I at least print out something to the console it is definitely not ignored.  I wonder if this error handling will prevent the JVM from shutting down since most errors result in the program completely crashing as if a meteor fell on the computer.  Thanks for the comment. I did not think about how this could be dangerous.  I remember from my studies that errors really should not be caught since they are terrible situations for a program to be in.

Comment: Printing something out on the console is almost certain to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try catching it is the best way to go about it. This also protects you in case you accidentally edit the url to `http//www.google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare it or try-catch it. There is no other way.

Compiler is not able to "check" if your address is malformated or not before running it.